# "500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()" - login failed on Debian

Tags: linux, ftp, debian-wheezy, chroot, vsftpd

I installed vsFTPd for running an FTP server on [Debian 7.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_7_(Wheezy)) (Wheezy). I checked the vsFTPd version was *2.3.5*, and I configured it like so:

```
listen=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
pasv_min_port=15000
pasv_max_port=15200
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

I followed these articles for solving this problem:

- http://blog.waja.info/2013/05/13/500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot/
- http://www.mikestechblog.com/joomla/operating-systems-section/operating-systems-ubuntu/155-500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot.html

And many others on Google and forums, but my problem was not solved.

NOTE: I have solved this problem on [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin), but that solution does not work on Debian 7.3.

I really mixed up on it?!

Comment: Both links seem to be broken (timeout and 404, respectively).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I'm sorry, this answer is too old so those links are broken by their provider. So, I can't do any thing for them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I searched for it toooooooooo much, and I really mixed up, so I decided to change vsFTPd to SFTP or something else, till I found a link about [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=735191#10).

Then I found out this problem was solved in vsFTPd version 3. So I searched how to upgrade it and could find to add the **jessie** repository to my Debian 7.3 installation and upgrade it so:

```
echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
aptitude update
aptitude upgrade vsftpd
echo "allow_writeable_chroot=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
service vsftpd restart
```

Now it works correctly for me.

Comment: You are right about the Jessie thing but I would not suggest people to just add a Jessie repository to Wheezy.  
It also wants to update libc and there is a good chance to destroy your disitribution that way.

Comment: Note that the `vsftpd` package is Free as in Freedom software, so the first command adding the `contrib` and `non-free` repositories is completely unrelated. Just an `apt update` and `apt upgrade` and enabling that option is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

to the configuration and restart the service with `service vsftpd restart`

Then "allow_writeable_chroot=YES" will work also with newer vsFTPd versions
(found in *[500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot() Keep user jailed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239239/500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot-keep-user-j)*).

Comment: For me it was enough to just add `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` to **/etc/vsftpd.conf**

Answer (score 0):

From the default `vsftpd.conf`:

> *Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the chroot*

That's why your solution should **not** involve `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` when applicable. Instead, refactor your filesystem in order to avoid writable FTP top level directories.